# Unable to proceed integration and commit the change

Tags: aegis

I have a change which is in awaiting integration stage.

When I issue aeib command, the output says, couple of file are altered.

I tried reverting the changes and make both w,D file and the current file same. Still no luck.

I am also unable to undo these files and begin a new change to push the latest files through that new change as it says the files are locked with another change.

I have been using aegis for 1.5 years and never had this strange issue. Leaning on you experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my god, I thought this problem will create huge issues to the progress of my devlopment and couldn't find much help from online as well. Went through the aegis reference manual and found that aedeu command could be my friend in this case and he is. Brought the change back to development phase and then I went on to build, review and integrate.